# Java HTTP/1.1 GET request BufferedReader readLine never stops

Tags: java, sockets, http, inputstream

Hello I'm making an HTTP client. I'm trying to fetch google.com's html code. I have a problem the the BufferedReader.readLine() function is blocking endlessly because the remote server apparently doesn't send a blank line? Or could it be that my request is wrong?

Appreciate any help!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String uri = "www.google.com";
        int port = 80;
        Socket socket = new Socket(uri, port);
        PrintWriter toServer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        get(uri, port, language, socket, toServer, inputStream);
}

public static void get(String uri, int port, String language, Socket socket, PrintWriter toServer, InputStream inputStream) {
        try {
            toServer.println("GET / HTTP/1.1");
            toServer.println("Host: " + uri + ":" + port);
            toServer.println();

            // Parse header
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            BufferedReader fromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
                while ((line = fromServer.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
            System.out.println("done");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: If you're making an HTTP client (why?) you need to read the HTTP RFCs, starting with RFC 2616. There are already several things wrong here in only a few lines of code. But don't continue with this, Java already has a built-in HTTP client, and there are others available. Don't roll your own. Too broad.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks for your response. I know this is pretty dumb but it's an assignment for my computer networks course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending a HTTP/1.1 request which by default enables HTTP keep-alive. This means that the server might keep the TCP connection open after the response was sent in order to accept more requests from the client. Your code instead assumes that the server will close the connection after the response was finished by explicitly expecting `readline` to return `null`. But since the server will not close the connection (or only after some long timeout) the `readline` will just block.

To fix this either use HTTP/1.0 (which has keep-alive off by default) instead of HTTP/1.1 or explicitly tell the server that no more requests will be send by adding a `Connection: close` header.

Please note that in general HTTP is way more complex than you might think if you've just seen a few examples. The problem you face in your question is only a glimpse into more problems which you will face when continuing this path. If you really want to implement your own HTTP handling instead of using established libraries please study the actual standard instead of just assuming a specific behavior.

Comment: He also needs to send a content-length with the request, otherwise the server can't even get started with processing it.

Comment: @user207421: Given that this is a GET request the body has an implicit length of 0 and thus no `Content-length` header is needed. Browsers don't send such a header with GET requests either. But one can definitely find more problems with the existing code, like using the wrong line delimiter (`\n` instead of `\r\n`).

Comment: Thank you for your response. The point is I don't think I want to close the connection as I want to do follow up GET requests on the image paths inside the html. The idea is getting the google html and its images so I can view the site completely locally without remote resources. (This is a university assignment). Or would you recommend closing the connection and then reopening for each image?

Comment: @DirkxSenne: If you want to keep the connection open you need to implement a proper HTTP parser in your code so that you can determine when the response actually ends instead of assuming `readLine` to magically have an understanding of HTTP. Closing the connection makes this easier. Again, please study the actual standard instead of just assuming things.